# org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V

Tags: java, spring, maven, restlet

hi i am trying to deploy my restlet project in tomcat i encountered with following exception. I found that its mismatch of the dependency versions if it is mis-match then which versions got mis-matched. If not then what else caused the exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:563)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)...
```

How can i resolve this problem This is my pom.xml dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cql</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

after modifying as you said my exception is changed to

```
 org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration.‌​<init>(Lorg/springfr‌​amework/expression/s‌​pel/SpelCompilerMode‌​;Ljava/lang/ClassLoa‌​der;)V
```

please help me with this

Comment: Looks like incompatible jars. Spring-web 3.2.8 and spring-Expression 4.2.0??

Comment: i tried changing spring-web to 4.2.0 still getting same exception

Comment: look into your classpath if you have different Versions of spring-core.

Comment: i have spring-core 4.2.0

Comment: only 4.2.0? and which Version of spring-context-Support?

Comment: yes,only 4.2.0... i can't find spring-context-Support but i have spring-context 3.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: so Change the Version to 4.2.0. you should have the same Version of all spring dependencies

Comment: It also looks like you are mixing apache camel versions... 2.7, 2.11 and 2.17...

Comment: please look the edited question